# How can i loop all audios from playlist with react native sound

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-sound

I am trying to make an audio player using react native and react-native-sound.

I want to loop all audios from playlist to play them one by one for a single time.  How can I do that?

here is my code:

```
const songs = [
    {
        title: 'one',
        url: 'one.mp3'
    },
    {
        title: 'two',
        url: 'two.mp3'
    },
    {
        title: 'three',
        url: 'three.mp3'
    },
    {
        title: 'four',
        url: 'four.mp3'
    },
];

function playSound(song) {
    song = new Sound(song.url, Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {
        if (error){
          //
        } else {
            song.play((success) => {
                song.release();
           });
        }
    });
}

function playAll() {
    Object.keys(songs).forEach(function(key) {
        playSound(songs[key])
    });
}
```

I tried using setTimeOut() for loop but don't know how to set Timeout duration exactly same as audio duration.